# What is a model lineage?

Tags: models

We know about the lineage of datasets. Is there anything called "(ML) model lineage". What are all the works that had been remarkable regarding "model lineage"?

There are few links available on internet which talk about model lineage. According to one of the articles[1], the definition of model lineage is as follows:

> Model Lineage keeps the history of a model: when it was trained, using which data, algorithms, and parameters. This should be automatically generated each time a new version of a model is generated.

The next reference that I could find on the internet is the session by data bricks[2].

Apart from these two links, I could not find many resources or standards regarding model lineage. It will be helpful if anyone could provide more resources or pointers towards this topic.

1. [https://blog.tail.digital/en/we-need-to-talk-about-model-lineage/#:~:text=Model%20Lineage%20keeps%20the%20history,of%20a%20model%20is%20generated](https://blog.tail.digital/en/we-need-to-talk-about-model-lineage/#:%7E:text=Model%20Lineage%20keeps%20the%20history,of%20a%20model%20is%20generated)
2. https://databricks.com/session_na20/machine-learning-data-lineage-with-mlflow-and-delta-lake

Comment: Can you please give some additional context? Perhaps some references where the phrase is used?

Comment: Hi Sathya. As pointed out by the pointer in the comment above, you write "We know about the lineage of datasets", but I also don't know what you mean by "lineage of datasets", so please edit your post to include more context (which may also include links and references to other resources where you read this term and that describes it, in addition to what you should do, i.e. describe what "lineage of models" are and why you're interested in "model lineage", whatever that means).

Comment: Hi, I have added some details to the question. I hope the additions I made will be useful.